# Do while loop in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a function:

```
isItSimple :: Int -> Bool
```

it gets Int and return Bool.

I need to find **first** number in [x | x <- [**n..**], isItSimple x].

Here is my solution:

```
findIt :: Int -> Int
findIt num
       | isItSimple num = num
       | otherwise = findIt (num + 1)
```

Is there any better solution in Haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases, especially when your problem is a particular case of solved one, explicit resursion is bad. One of possible solutions of your problem without using explicit recursion is:

```
import Data.List (find)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

findIt :: Int -> Int
findIt n = fromJust $ find isItSimple [n..]
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the complexity of the problem and the solution? If explicit recursion is simpler than knowing about find and fromJust, shouldn't one prefer using explicit recursion?

Comment: @Jaywalker: It is exactly the same, and more elegant.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on what "explicit recursion is bad" means. Bad performance? Uglyness?

Comment: @MartinCapodici Mostly ugliness. Someone has already solved your problem, why solve it again? It is also often easier to read, because the function names describes what you are doing.

Answer (score 20):

> I need to find **first** number in [x | x <- [n..], isItSimple x].

How about just like you said.

```
findIt n = head [ x | x <- [n..], isItSimple x ]
```

Comment: Definitly preferable over `fromJust`.

Comment: @FUZxxl I don't like `fromJust` in general but in this case, it's exactly the same as `head`, I mean having no `x` above `n` satisfying `isItSimple` will yield "bottom".  We would never evaluate `head []` nor `fromJust Nothing` anyway.

Answer (score 14):

While the other answers work, they're arguably not the most idiomatic way to solve this problem in Haskell. You don't really need any extra imports: a couple of functions from the Prelude will do the trick.

I'd start by creating a list of all of the simple numbers greater than or equal to `n`. The function `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` makes this easy:

```
filter isItSimple [n..]
```

Like `[n..]` this is an infinite list, but this isn't a problem since Haskell is lazy and won't evaluate anything until it's needed.

To get what you want you can just take the head of this infinite list:

```
findIt :: Int -> Int
findIt n = head $ filter isItSimple [n..]
```

Some people don't like `head` since it's a partial function and will raise an exception when it's given an empty list. I personally wouldn't worry about that here, since we know it will never be called on an empty list. It makes me much less uncomfortable than `fromJust`, which is also a partial function (it raises an exception when given `Nothing`) and in my opinion is always a bad idea.

(And speaking of personal taste, I'd write this as follows:

```
findIt = head . filter isItSimple . enumFrom
```

This is an example of [pointfree](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style, which can get convoluted but in this case is very elegant, in my opinion.)

Comment: Worrying about `head` or `fromJust` is superfluous in this case anyhow, since if no simple numbers exist the program will go into an infinite loop first. But I agree that `fromJust` is almost never a good idea; at least use `fromMaybe (error "What? Inconceivable!")` to make it obvious what is going on.

Comment: @camccann: Right, but for me the worrying is more a matter of developing better coding habits. I think I write nicer code if I force myself to pretend that `fromJust` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
findIt :: Int -> Int
findIt num = head $ dropWhile (not isItSimple) [num..]
```

I don't know if it's better. It just came to my mind.

Comment: should've been `(not . isItSimple)`, with the dot (function composition).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the least fixed point combinator (fix in Data.Function)

```
findIt = fix (\f x ->  if isItSimple x then x else f (x + 1))
```

In this case it looks a little bit over-engineered, but if the "search space" follows a more complicated rule than `x + 1` this technique can be quite useful.

Comment: Don't mistake fix for being anything other than recursion.  By mechanical substitution:  `findIt x = if isItSimple x then x else findIt (x + 1)`.

Comment: IOW, `head . dropWhile (not . isItSimple) . iterate (1+)`, or even just `until isItSimple (1+)`.